# Android Voice Recognition: how to auto end listening to voice after one sentence and result to activityResult

Tags: android, voice-recognition

here my code .
I want to make like google now, just talk one sentence, after that recognizer auto End and go to ActivityResult 
Pls !

On start

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Speak now...");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

On activity result

```
ArrayList<String> matches = data
                .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

Comment: Dont know if this helps, can you detect pause for 1 or 2 sec and stop recording. Well in your recording it wont be a flat signal even when the user doesnt speak, there will be some noise. So setting some threshold or using some noise filtering mechanism I think you can detect pause

Comment: This used to work for me, i.e. it used to recognize when it was finished. Now, I guess with recent android updates, it waits for 5 or 6 seconds after speech stops before ending. I think it actually doesn't recognize the silence, because setting `EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS` doesn't seem to help. Funny how Google Now works fine...